# asp.net mvc 3 - filter, sort data from more then 1 table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, filter

I have 4 parameters to filter (two dropdownlists and two datetime type fields) data from my database. I take data from 3 tables of this database. The view should be like the view on the screen. How can I do it? Simple gridview don't present data like i want.

How can I send 4 parameters to controller?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd84f.png]

I am using Oracle Database

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with your question to get some decent answers. Are you using basic ADO.NET with sprocs / parameterize SQL, LINQ to SQL, some ORM framework? How are you querying for data and how is that data structured?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can make select with LINQ:

```
var list = (from t1 in DataContext.Tables1
//here add you joins
select new
{
   Code = t1.Code,
   CompanyName = t1.Company, //for example
   //...
}).ToList();

GridView.DataSource = list;
GridView.DataBind();
```

But this will work only if you use "hybrid" application - both classic ASP and MVC approach. Otherwise you need pass list to your view.

About parameters... For example you have layout

```
<select name="filter1">
//...
<select>

<select name="filter2">
//...
<select>

<input type="hidden" name="dateStart" />
<input type="hidden" name="dateEnd" />
```

Then in you action you will have:

```
    public ActionResult MyAction(int filter1, string filter2, DateTime? dateStart, DateTime? dateEnd)
    {
        //code here
        return View();
    }
```